# Can a single-file command line tool written in objective-c handle a URL Scheme?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, macos, url-scheme

Using Xcode, is it possible to create an Objective-C or C single-file tool (i.e, no app bundle) that handles a custom URL schema?

I've added `-sectcreate __TEXT __info_plist Info.plist_path` into my **other linker flags** and below is my info.plist that is supposed to be added to the binary (not sure how I can confirm that is is being added). But, building the binary doesn't result in `myCoolURLHandler://key=value` being handled by the new tool.

I've very new to objective-c and Xcode, so I am sure I am missing something.

My info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>Apple.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>0.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>URLHandlerTestApp</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>myCoolURLHandler</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```